# How to destroy a DOM element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom

Suppose the jQuery object is `$target`.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

Is `$target.remove();` what you're looking for?

https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: Of course this only removes it from the visible document. If there are other references to the node from JavaScript, such as the $target variable itself, the object will escape the garbage collector for now. If you want to DESTROY it you also have to lose all references to it. I'm not quite sure why you'd want to DESTROY a DOM element though. Maybe you just hate $target. Poor $target, what did it ever do to you?

Comment: $target is kind when he's alone, but he gets nasty when he is around his 100.000 cloned friends.

Comment: Will `.empty()` have a similar effect?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda - Empty will remove the contents of the object, but doesn't remove (or destroy) the object itself.

Answer (score 47):

If you want to *completely destroy* the target, you have a couple of options. First you can remove the object from the DOM as described above...

```
console.log($target);   // jQuery object
$target.remove();       // remove target from the DOM
console.log($target);   // $target still exists
```

**Option 1** - Then replace target with an **empty jQuery object** (jQuery 1.4+)

```
$target = $();
console.log($target);   // empty jQuery object
```

**Option 2** - Or **delete the property** entirely (will cause an error if you reference it elsewhere)

```
delete $target;
console.log($target);   // error: $target is not defined
```

More reading: [info about empty jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897331/getting-an-empty-jquery-object), and [info about delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Comment: Why `delete $target` will not work:
http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#misconceptions

Why won't `$target=null` work?

Comment: @LeeGee - Can you please summarize your post to explain why delete won't work for jQuery objects? Why does it appear to work when we look at console.log($target) at the end? Thank you.

Comment: I cannot explain it any better than the article cited, which I found very detailed.

Comment: For the record, this works in console because console evaluates JS in the scope of eval, which allows delete. Variables in "natural" scopes will not be deletable.  Use `$target=null` instead.  It is faster and doesn't mess with internal browser optimizations.

Comment: @bendman - Do you have any sources that talk about natural scopes not being deletable, or using null instead? If there's a good source to reference, I'll add this as another option in the answer.

Comment: @Luke Actually, that link above has it, albeit at a different anchor: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/#firebug_confusion

Comment: For what it's worth, `delete` does appear to do exactly what `remove()` didn't for me; with `'remove()`, references to the objects seemed to be retained and were still causing lagging issues with other on-screen elements even after being `remove()`d (these were very large background images with animated SVGs). Using `delete` appears to have *actually* destroyed them as I was hoping, and cleared up the subsequent lag. I get it may be inappropriate for some uses, but it works exactly as expected with jQuery DOM element references.

Comment: Delete is fine. It just means that block won't be optimized by the JS engine. In most cases, that is entirely irrelevant. When it becomes an issue, then you look for ways around using delete. Not before.

Answer (score 16):

You are looking for the `.remove()` function.

http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/remove

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's just me, but using .remove() doesn't seem to work if you are selecting by an id.

Ex:  $("#my-element").remove();

I had to use the element's class instead, or nothing happened.

Ex:  $(".my-element").remove();