# Remove div based on its class value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I've been trying to remove a div based on its class value, but I fail to succeed. You might say that I can use the ID instead, but this element doesn't have any ID.

```
<body class="home_page">
<div id="visas">
<div class="ikur"> <!-- I want to remove this div -->
...
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: just: $('.ikur').remove();

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to destroy a DOM element with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391793/how-to-destroy-a-dom-element-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this you want :

```
$(function() {
    $('div.ikur').remove();
});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8mfwF/)

Answer (score 0):

Just try with [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/):

```
$('.ikur').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.remove()`:

```
$('.classname').remove();
```

For example:

```
$('.ikur').remove();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Rg45T/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `.remove()` [jQuery help link](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Example in your case  if you want to remove `div` based on class name then use following

```
$('.ikur').remove();
```

I have set up a fiddle example incase you want to remove div under specific wrapper div or may want to remove all div with particular call [example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/vCsJ8/)

You can play around & make it work according to your requirements