# Javascript + Knockout.js memory leak - How to make sure object is being destroyed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory, knockout.js, memory-leaks

I am using [google's 3 Snapshot method](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1wUVmf78gG-ra5aOxvTfYdiLkdGaR9OhXRnOlIcEmu2s/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000#slide=id.g14717ff3_0_23) to find memory leaks on the page.
Page is running on Knockout.js and Jquery Mobile UI.
I have already narrowed down to one of memory leaking divs. Between each snapshot I am running this script to clear the memory leaking object.

```
$('.paddedContentContainer').children().each(function(index,item){
console.log(item); 
$(item).off(); 
ko.cleanNode($(item)); 
$(item).remove();
item = null;
});
```

.paddedContentContainer is parent of leaking object.
Now the interesting part is that I can still see object in retained object tree. In screenshot below you can see I am filtering on objects in Snapshot 3 that are retained from Snapshots 1 and 2, and by text it's visible that `$0` from console in same object that is on the screen (Event Sales Order & ....).
[image]

I am assuming that  `.off();`  and `.remove();` isin't enough for object to be collected.
**How to destroy all references to this object for good?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an answer for those who will be satisfied with `knockout.js` reference removal only. 
This removed `<div>` at hand from object tree.

```
 $('.paddedContentContainer').children().each(function(index,item){
     $(item).off(); 
     ko.removeNode(item);
     $(item).remove();
     item = null;
 });
```

Comment: I think this is wrong, setting item to none wont effect the reference held internally by knockout, have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/jy3MK/

Comment: @Metalstorm nope it certainly does, and clearNode() does not. You are more than welcome to try it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`.remove()` just removes the element from the DOM, if anything is still referencing it (in your code) it will not be Garbage Collected.

**Edit**

Yes the `.remove()` is the correct way of detaching/removing it from the DOM, but it is still held in memory because other things are referencing it (knockout's internals in this example).

One way, and the way I do it, is to keep a collection of all the high-level DOM elements that I create in my controls, then have a destroy function that loops these and calls `.remove()` on them and assigns them to `null`

E.g (Note this is held within each control object (no leaky global stuff):

```
var elements = 
{
    'table' : $('#some_table'),
    'button' : $('#some_button')
};


function destroy()
{
    for(var key in elements)
    {
        elements[key].remove();
        elements[key] = null;
    }
}
```

You may be able to take this approach with knockout.

Comment: how do I find everything that is referencing that element? .off() should remove all event handlers, what about all the other stuff?

Comment: Ummm the inspector might have a way of seeing all references? One of the columns / right click?

Comment: Oh absolutely. I already know it's knockout holding it's hands on object (function (){return c++ +d}), I must misphrased myself. How do I get generic mechanism to get rid of all references to any DOM element, there must be a way of detaching element.

Comment: Edited my answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this post: [How to destroy a DOM element with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391793/how-to-destroy-a-dom-element-with-jquery)?

Luke's response seems interesting:

> If you want to completely destroy the target, you have a couple of
>   options. First you can remove the object from the DOM as described
>   above...
>
> console.log($target);   // jQuery object $target.remove();       //
>   remove target from the DOM console.log($target);   // $target still
>   exists Option 1 - Then replace target with an empty jQuery object
>   (jQuery 1.4+)
>
> $target = $(); console.log($target);   // empty jQuery object Option 2
>   - Or delete the property entirely (will cause an error if you reference it elsewhere)
>
> delete $target; console.log($target);   // error: $target is not
>   defined

Maybe you should to `delete $(item)` in the end.

Comment: this is really good example to destroy Javascript object no DOM elements http://snag.gy/bngFD.jpg in screenshot you can see item getting deleted and then myself evaluating it out in console.

Comment: I can see you wrote $0 in the console. I'm saying you should try `delete $0`

Comment: $0 is special command to get data out of Chrome Developer tools when inspecting heap.

Comment: What's wrong with trying `delete $(item)`? As Metalstorm said, if the DOM object is still there it is probably because it is still referenced

Comment: it does not get deleted you can see it in screenshot I have sent you.

Comment: I suggested to do it **in the end**, after `$(item).remove();`

Comment: Remember doing console.log(item) is probably going to hold a reference to the object (so you can inspect it later in the console)