# Delete contents of <th>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to javascript/jquery. I have a table that has an index column (0,1,2,3 etc). I would like to delete that part of the table using javascript. I tried to use after() and replaceWith() but couldn't really get it right.

The css class is .jobStats. I would like to ONLY remove contents of th tag in the code below.

```
   <tr>
  <th>0 </th>
  <td> 2015-06-02</td>
  <td>              ARCA</td>
  <td>   FAILED</td>
  <td>2015-06-03 10:30:51.573000</td>
  <td>                NaT</td>
  <td>                NaT</td>
  <td> NaN</td>
  <td>   NaN</td>
  <td>       NaN</td>
  <td>  8704</td>
  <td> 223226518</td>
  <td>   NaN</td>
  <td>   NaN</td>
</tr>
```

Any thoughts on how I can achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to destroy a DOM element with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391793/how-to-destroy-a-dom-element-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

```
$('.jobStats').remove();
```

If you wish to keep `.jobStats` and want to remove its children, use [empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)

```
$('.jobStats').empty();
```

**Update**

> I only want to remove the contents of the th tag in the table.

```
$('th').empty();
```

will remove **both** children and text

> This method removes not only child (and other descendant) elements,
>   but also any text

Comment: I only want to remove the contents of the th tag in the table. However, the problem is that when i remove that, it also remove the header.

I tried this as well:
    $('tbody th').remove()

But that distorts the header because there is still space for the index column there.

 $('tbody th').empty()   looks better

Answer (score 1):

You can use `empty()`

```
$( ".jobStats" ).empty();
```

From the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)

> Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

as already some had say .remove() does the work, but keept in mind .detach() as .remove() also remove event handlers (like click, double click , etc), and detach only remove it from DOM but leaves events, so u can detach it now, and atach it again later, with the events intact.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by

```
 $("#yourElementID").remove();

 $(".yourClass").remove();

 $("yourHTMLelement").remove();
```

Hope this helps