# How to create an empty jQuery result

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Edit**: As of jQuery 1.4, using `$()` will work as described below.

---

I need to loop through an array and create a number of elements which I want to have in a single jQuery result object.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    $myJQueryObj = $myJQueryObj.add($("<span>blahblah</span>"));
}
```

The problem with this, however, is that you need a jQuery object to begin with, and you obviously want to start it empty. In the above example, how should I initialise `$myJQueryObj` ?

The following examples do not work, as they all select the document object:

```
$('')
$()
$(null)
$(false)
```

These do work... but...

```
$('#nonExistantElement')  // yuck
$().slice(0,0)            // surely there's a nicer way?
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yep. Try `$([])`. The reason `$()` doesn't work is because that jQuery expects a context, and without any supplied, will default to `document` as the context. Many things depend on this assumption being true, so changing `$()` to mean "give me the empty set" would be problematic at best.

Answer (score 16):

Ah, I figured it out just after I wrote the question. Here's what I found, in case anyone else is interested:

```
$([])
```