# Create jquery object var

Tags: jquery

I would like to replicate jquery object selection, for example

When i select multiple objects with

```
var test = $(".someclass");
```

I get the object with all selected objects with that class.

Now how could i keep adding objects in that war, something like `test.push($(".somediv"));`

Also i saw `.add( jQuery object )` but it gives me error `Cannot call method 'add' of null`
when i try to add object to an empty variable

Also how can i create jquery variable with no values and then add them later?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting an empty JQuery object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897331/getting-an-empty-jquery-object) -- and you already know `.add` as far as I can tell.

Comment: Better duplicate: [jQuery add elements to empty selection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533929/jquery-add-elements-to-empty-selection).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `$()` to create an empty jQuery object and then you can use `.add()` to add more items to it via a selector:

```
var items = $().add(".someClass");
items = items.add(".someDiv");
```

When using `.add()`, just remember that it returns a NEW jQuery objects that have the new elements added in.  It does not modify the original jQuery object.  It's easy to forget that and do:

```
items.add(".someDiv");
```

and wonder why nothing is added to `items` (this has bit me several times).

Comment: Ah, that explains it, then. I saw that you'd (re-) edited to add new stuff, but hadn't realised that the omission of the quote was caused by an edit-race (for want of a better word). Just wondered if you knew something (else...) that I didn't. =)

Answer (score 1):

**jfriend00** solution is what you'd use with modern version of jQuery. I use this a lot too:

```
var classes = ['foo', 'bar', 'bla', 'asd'];
var $els = $('.'+ classes.join('.,'));
```

Comment: That's not adding elements though, it's selecting all of them at once.

Comment: **@Felix Kling** I don't think it makes a difference, it depends on the situation tho. If you already have an object you can always do this `$el.add('.'+ classes.join('.,'))` and it would be the same as adding four times.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
var objects = $().add(".className").add(".divName");
```

Comment: Jquery: Write less, do more :)