# How to design a jQuery plugin that depends on the page having been loaded?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a jQuery plugin that starts off like this:

```
$.fn.kewTip = (function() {
    var $kewtip = $('<div></div>').css({'position':'absolute','zIndex':2147483647}).attr({'class':'kewtip'}).hide().appendTo('body');
```

You will notice that it immediately appends an element to the page body, but it can't do that until the DOM is ready, which means the plugin can't be defined until the DOM is ready either.

However, I'd ideally like calls to `$('xxx').kewTip()` to not fail if they try calling it outside of `$(document).ready({ ... })`. So how do I get around this?

My plugin depends on this element existing, so how do I define it before the DOM is ready?

Comment: Can't you just add a `document ready callback` inside the plugin, and do your stuffs inside that? I am not sure if that's the best way but that should work.

Comment: @Joy: Yeah, I guess that's plausible. I just have to set the 1 var as soon as the DOM's ready.

Comment: *"However, I'd ideally like calls to `$('xxx').kewTip()` to not fail if they try calling it outside of `$(document).ready({ ... })`."* ... Why shouldn't it? It's the user's obligation to call the plugin at the right moment. Does it make sense at all to call this method if `xxx` does not exist yet? Or is the element appended as soon as the plugin is loaded? It's not clear only from the part you posted and you seem to refer to both, the definition of the plugin (first paragraph) and calling the plugin (second paragraph).

Comment: @FelixKling: Absolutely. The plugin just binds some events. The events won't work until the DOM is ready, but they should be able to bind at any time.

Comment: I agree with @FelixKling. You shouldn't do all the job to secure the developer's calls.

Answer (score 4):

If all you want to do is to be certain that the `div` exists when the plugin method is called the first time, then just create it. In order to work with the element (append elements, event handlers) it does not have to be added to the DOM.

Then, independently, add the element to `body` when the DOM is loaded.

For example:

```
$.fn.kewTip = (function() {
    // create element
    var $kewtip = $('<div />', {
        'class': 'kewtip',
        'style': 'position:absolute;zIndex:2147483647;display:none'
     });

    // add to DOM once it is ready
    $(function() {
        $kewtip.appendTo('body');
    });

    return function() {
        // here you can do whatever with `$kewtip` no matter whether it was 
        // already appended to body or not
    }
}());
```

*(I assume you have a self invoking function there)*

Comment: Oo...I like your solution even better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Joy's suggestion, I came up with this:

```
$.fn.kewTip = (function() {
    var $kewtip = $();
    $(function() {
        $kewtip = $('<div></div>').css({'position':'absolute','zIndex':2147483647}).hide().appendTo('body');
    });
```

`$()` just gives an [an empty jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/897341/65387) so the rest of the code doesn't fail catastrophically before it's ready.